# How can we make gRPCServer talk to another gRPCServer?

Tags: grpc

I am newbie to gRPC, and have task to make one gRPCServer accepts as proxy to the other gRPCServer.   and I read "   In HTTP/2, the CONNECT method is used to establish a tunnel over a    single HTTP/2 stream to a remote host for similar purposes". I am using gRPC with cpp.
Could you please help with pointers for the same.
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) have a look around, and read through the [HELP center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), then read [How to Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and provide a [MCVE : Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If people around can easily read and understand what you mean, or what the problem is, they'll be more likely willing to help :)

Answer (score 0):

gRPC does not support CONNECT over HTTP/2. It only supports using CONNECT to connect to an HTTP/2 server through an HTTP/1 forward proxy, like the standard feature of browsers and HTTP libraries.